# Proper usage of \limits in math mode

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and I'm trying to write properly integrals in my notes.
Here's an example of the code:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \,dz\]
$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \,dz$
\end{document}
```

The problem is the way the limit is shown in the two versions.

[image] versus [image]

In summary: I need to put the second limit in an `array` (as follows) but I would like to display the first version instead of the second one.

```tex
\begin{itemize}
    \item se $t < a$, allora
    \[\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{t} 0 \cdot \,dz = 0\]
    \item se $a \le x \le b$, allora
    $$
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \,dz & = & \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a} 0 \cdot \,dz +
        \int\limits_{a}^{t} \dfrac{1}{b-a} \,dz \\
        & = & \dfrac{z}{b-a}\bigg\rvert_a^t = \dfrac{t-a}{b-a};
    \end{array}
    $$
    \item se $t > b$, allora
    $$
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \,dz & = & \int\limits_{-\infty}^{a} 0 \cdot \,dz +
        \int\limits_{a}^{b} \dfrac{1}{b-a} \,dz + \int\limits_{b}^{t} 0 \cdot \,dz\\
        & = & \dfrac{z}{b-a}\bigg\rvert_a^t = 1;
    \end{array}
    $$
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...not sure... are you looking for `\int\nolimits`?

Comment: Also, `$$` is not LaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: use `\displaystyle` at the beginning of your lines where you need to display the limits in your first version, and you can remove the `\limits`

Comment: `array` is the wrong tool here. You want to use a displayed alignment like `align*`.

Comment: @Rmano \nolimits was not actually what I was looking for, but thanks for the second hint about why `$$` is not LaTeX!

Comment: @needle Thanks for your comment and your following answer, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @campa Actually I haven't thought about `align*` thanks, mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `\displaystyle`, but here it is better to use the `align*` environment.
Also instead of doing `\,d` each time, i recommend you define a macro like for example `\def\diff{\,\mathrm{d}}`. So each time you what to call it you just do `\diff` and it will do it for you, and you will make less mistakes that way.
Also it is better to use `\(` or `\)` to open or close inline math, rather that `$`

Here is what it would look like using `align*`

```
%%% Define before the document %%%%
\def\diff{\,\mathrm{d}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item se \(t < a\), allora
            \[\int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \diff z = \int_{-\infty}^{t} 0 \cdot\diff z = 0\]

        \item se \(a \le x \le b\), allora
        \begin{align*}
            \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \diff z  &=  \int_{-\infty}^{a} 0 \cdot \diff z + \int_{a}^{t} \dfrac{1}{b-a} \diff z \\
            &= \dfrac{z}{b-a}\bigg\rvert_a^t \\
            &= \dfrac{t-a}{b-a};
        \end{align*}
        
        \item se \(t > b\), allora
        \begin{align*}
            \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_X(z) \diff z &=  \int_{-\infty}^{a} 0 \cdot \diff z + \int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{1}{b-a} \diff z + \int_{b}^{t} 0 \cdot \,dz \\
            &= \dfrac{z}{b-a}\bigg\rvert_a^t \\
            &= 1;
        \end{align*}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

Comment: `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}` will only add the thin space when required, for instance, it won't in the case `0\cdot\diff z`. Note that the OP *doesn't* use `\mathrm{d}` and the answer shouldn't as well.

Comment: @egreg to be honest I'm coding LaTeX on VSC, and I used the standard structures offered by the IDE. I thought they were right. So can I ask you which is the proper way to write the diff in LaTeX? Thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't place the equations on separate lines *below* the "se ... allora" conditionals. Separately, I wouldn't insert `\cdot` before `dz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Se $t < a$, allora
    $\displaystyle
      \int_{-\infty}^{t}\! f_X(z) \,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \!0 \,dz = 0$
    \item Se $a \le t \le b$, allora
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
      \int_{-\infty}^{t}\! f_X(z) \,dz &= 
         \int_{-\infty}^{a} \!0 \,dz +
         \int_{a}^{t} \frac{1}{b-a} \,dz \\
         &= \frac{z}{b-a} \bigg\vert_a^t = \frac{t-a}{b-a}
    \end{aligned}$
    \item Se $t > b$, allora
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
      \int_{-\infty}^{t}\! f_X(z) \,dz 
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{a} \!0 \,dz +
         \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{b-a} \,dz + 
         \int_{b}^{t} \!0 \,dz\\
      &= \frac{z}{b-a} \bigg\vert_a^b = 1\,.
    \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```